# Using Symbolic C++ in user-defined classes

Tags: c++

I have a function while I would like to manipulate symbolically as well as numerically. That is, take derivatives as well as evaluate the function at certain points. I thought, perhaps incorrectly, the best way to do this in generality would be to have a user defined class with two member functions: one that provides the derivative (with all the symbolic c++ stuff being private) and the other that does the substitution and spits out the function value when provided with parameter and variable values.

However, I am having some trouble constructing the symbolic bits within the private class member bit:

```
class fitFunction {
    Symbolic t("t"), A("A"), B("B");
    float p1, p2, time;
    Symbolic fn= A*(1-exp(-B*t));
public:
    fitFunction(vector<float> &, float );
    float evaluate() {
        return fn[A == p1, B == p2, t == time];
    }

};

fitFunction::fitFunction (vector<float>  & pars, float tt) {
p1 = pars[0];
p2 = pars[1];
time = tt;
}
```

I used the rather sloppy 'tt' definition to avoid possible conflicts with the symbolic version, but the main error I get is: "Expected identifier before string constant" with an arrow pointing to the Symbolic definition of "t", and all the others as well. Obviously since these aren't declared properly, everything else craps out.

It is perhaps worth pointing out the symbolic definitions and manipulations work fine in main().

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the class members in the constructor.  You can't initialize them directly as you are attempting to do.  There is no syntax for doing so; your attempt to do so is therefore a syntax error.

Try using these member declarations:

```
Symbolic t, A, B;
float p1, p2, time;
Symbolic fn;
```

Then, initialize these using the initializer list in the constructor:

```
fitFunction::fitFunction(vector<float> & pars, float tt)
    : t("t"),
      A("A"),
      B("B"),
      p1(pars[0]),
      p2(pars[1]),
      time(tt),
      fn(A * (1 - exp(-B * t)))
{
}
```